# How to assign a computed variable from one yml file to another yml file in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have an yml file, all.yml which has a dictionary defined as,

```
my_dict:
variable1: true
variable2: some_string
variable3: "dummy"
```

From another yml file, I am computing the variable3.
Here, how do I assign the newly computed variable3 to the one defined in all.yml?

```
my_dict.variable3: "{{ new_variable3 }}"
```

The above statement throws an error, "The variable name 'my_dict.variable3' is not valid. Variables must start with a letter or underscore character, and contain only letters, numbers and underscores."

Comment: you want to assign a variable into a second playbook from content of  another variable defined in first playbook?

Comment: your error mean you cant assign directly an item of dict

Comment: @Frenchy, Not from the content of another variable defined in first playbook.

Comment: @Frenchy, Not from the content of another variable defined in first playbook.
I have 2 yml files. 1st file has a dictionary my_dict with some key->value elements.
2nd file will compute the actual value of variable3 and need to assign it in the 1st yml file. This variable3 will be read in future files as well.

Comment: Your second yml cant  have a variable as you say.  See  my  precedent comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

this way to do does the job:

```
# file 1.yml
my_dict:
  variable1: true
  variable2: some_string
  variable3: "dummy"
```

---

```
# file 2.yml
my_dict:
  variable3: "newdummy"
```

---

```
- name: test 
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - 1.yml
  tasks:
    - name: display my_dict before modification
      debug:
        var: my_dict

    - name: apply modification to my_dict
      set_fact:
        my_dict: "{{ my_dict | combine(_temp.my_dict) }}"
      vars:
        _temp: "{{ lookup('file','2.yml') | from_yaml }}"

    - name: display my_dict after modification
      debug:
        var: my_dict
```

result:

```
TASK [display my_dict before modification] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  my_dict:
    variable1: true
    variable2: some_string
    variable3: dummy


TASK [display my_dict before modification] **********************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  my_dict:
    variable1: true
    variable2: some_string
    variable3: newdummy
```

Answer (score 0):

For my problem, I tried the below method and it worked.
so, to modify or re-assign the variable3 in one yml file from another yml file, I need to do

```
-name: assign variable3
 set_fact:
   my_dict:
      variable3: "{{ new_variable3 }}"
```

Comment: yes of course, its not a problem but its not the right answer to your question !! see my fixed answer..  and please, dont forget to close the question by upvoting and validating my or your answer..